# Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. useState not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I made a react native application with expo and I want to make a textfield that i can use. For this I wanted to use a useState of React, because this is the best way I read. Now I get the error:
Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import {Link} from 'expo-router';

export default function AddPartyPage() {
    // TODO fix state methods
    const [title, onChangeTitle] = useState<String>('Useless Text');
    const [description, onChangeDescription] = useState<String>('Useless Text');
    const [location, onChangeLocation] = useState<String>('Useless Text');
    return (
        <View>
            <Link href={{
                pathname: "/",
            }}>Back</Link>
            <View style={styles.textField}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Name: </Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => onChangeTitle(text)} value={title}></TextInput>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.textField}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Description: </Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => onChangeDescription(text)} value={description}></TextInput>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.textField}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Location: </Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => onChangeLocation(text)} value={location}></TextInput>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textField: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    text: {
        height: 40,
        width: 100
    },
    input: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default function AddPartyPage() {
  // TODO fix state methods
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Useless Text");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("Useless Text");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("Useless Text");

  const onChangeTitle = (text) => {
    console.log("use console a lot", text);
    setTitle(text);
  };

  const onChangeDescription = (text) => {
    console.log("if data is not here then use text.event.data", text);
    setDescription(text);
  };

  const onChangeLocation = (text) => {
    console.log(
      "if data is not here then use text.event.data below in setlocation",
      text
    );
    setLocation(text);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: "/",
        }}
      >
        Back
      </Link>
      <View style={styles.textField}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Name: </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeTitle(text)}
          value={title}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.textField}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Description: </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeDescription(text)}
          value={description}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.textField}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Location: </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeLocation(text)}
          value={location}
        ></TextInput>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I thought I already tried it, but apparently not. Thank you!!